# Angular Js: get $localStorage value in view page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a small app using Angular Js, and I am storing a value in `$localStorage` inside a Controller. Now I want to use that value in view page(.html page).

Can someone please suggest how can I do that?

Comment: Assign the `$localStorage` variable to a `$scope` variable and use that in your view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Local Storage data into the view file Using Angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241835/how-to-get-the-local-storage-data-into-the-view-file-using-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

**Local Storage**

*Set and get data with* `localStorage` in ***JavaScript*** :

```
localStorage.setItem("storageKey", "storedValueGoesHere"); //save into local storage
var test = localStorage.getItem("storageKey"); //get value from local storage
console.log(test); //Logs "storedValueGoesHere"
```

**Usage in AngularJS**

*I am assuming you are referring to `ngStorage` module*

use ngStorage js file like this (make sure you load it **after** `angularjs` is loaded, notice the order of `script` tags) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ngstorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
```

Now, inject `$localStorage` service in your controller

```
angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']).controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $localStorage) {  
                $scope.modelToBeDisaplyedinView = '';
                $scope.Save = function () {
                $localStorage.LocalMessage = "save some text here !";
            }
            $scope.Get = function () {
                $scope.modelToBeDisaplyedinView = $localStorage.LocalMessage ;
            });
```

**HTML**

Now display this in your view like this

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="Save()" />
        <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="Get()" />
<p ng-bind="modelToBeDisaplyedinView "></p>

<p> {{modelToBeDisaplyedinView }}</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, which is connected to your `html-view Template`, `Inject $localStorage`.

And then you can use all functionality and values from `$localStorage` in your view

For exaple ;

```
$scope.testValue = $localStorage.nameOfFunction
```

And in your view you can show it with interpolation like

```
{{ testValue }}
```